# Swooped down on someone

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrases

The following quote is from the movie *Coach Carter*. The basketball team is in a locker room after a game they lost. They're arguing with each other and one of them says:

> We had nothing but 32 points. I got 12 of them. What did you get,
>   Kenyon?

Another team member answers him:

> Just shut up, dog. The Crane swooped down on you and delivered a
>   basket of beat-down. He clowned you, dog.

What does *swooped down on you* mean here?

Comment: If you can't understand [*swooped down*](http://www.yourdictionary.com/swoop) (which will be clearly explained by *every* dictionary), how on earth could you hope to understand *a basket of beat-down* (which I doubt would be in *any* dictionary), or *he clowned you* (which I can only guess at, and again wouldn't expect to find in a dictionary).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Well, yes. [That](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/swoop+down+on) dictionary explains that, but in not a not-clear way....

Comment: @FumbleFingers basket of beat-down seems clearer to me. I think he takled about beating the team... I guess.

Comment: Some AmE speakers use [***cranes** instead of **storks***](https://ca.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20101109224646AAu57sn) for the "baby delivery" nursery story sense. It's an absolute cert the scriptwriters intended that allusion, but I don't think it works very well (it's unlikely any speaker who addresses other people as "dog" would use upmarket "delivered" instead of plain "gave"). You're dealing with smart-ass scriptwriters finely-honed wit here, not a faithful reflection of how actual basketball players speak to each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Swooped down" is to enforce the metaphor of a bird descending rapidly so as to attack some form of prey.